# How does one retrieve the public_token for Plaid API in Python

Tags: python-3.x, plaid

I'm trying to follow Plaid's documentation [from here](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-python) and I can't seem to figure out where do I get the `public_token` from when I'm working on Plaid **development** environment. They're saying that:

In their second example:

```py
from plaid import Client


client = Client(client_id='***', secret='***', public_key='***', environment='sandbox')

# the public token is received from Plaid Link
response = client.Item.public_token.exchange(public_token)
access_token = response['access_token']
```

I don't know where the `public_token` comes from. If I go to that [Plaid Link](https://github.com/plaid/link) they say:

> This repository is now deprecated. To integrate with Plaid, visit the
>   docs. https://plaid.com/docs

Then, when I go to their [official docs](https://plaid.com/docs) I can't seem to find any way of getting that `public token`.

I'm trying to do something along these lines:

```py
from exceptions import (
    InvalidPlaidEnvironment,
    MissingPlaidCredential
)

from plaid import Client
from plaid.errors import APIError, ItemError, InvalidRequestError


VALID_ENVIRONMENTS = (
    'sandbox',
    'development',
    'production'
)

CLIENT_ID = '<development_client_id>'
SECRET = '<development_secret>'
PUBLIC_KEY = '<development_public_key>'
ENVIRONMENT = 'development'


class PlaidProcessor:
    """
    Simple processor class for Plaid API
    """

    def __init__(
            self,
            client_id=CLIENT_ID,
            secret=SECRET,
            public_key=PUBLIC_KEY,
            environment=ENVIRONMENT
    ):
        """
        Constructor for PlaidProcessor. Initialize our class with basic credentials
        data.

        Args:
            client_id (str): Plaid client ID
            secret (str): Plaid secret
            public_key (str): Plaid public key
            environment (str): One of sandbox, development, or production
        """

        self.client_id = client_id
        self.secret = secret
        self.public_key = public_key
        self.environment = environment

        if not self.client_id:
            raise MissingPlaidCredential(
                'Missing CLIENT_ID. Please provide Plaid client id.'
            )

        if not self.secret:
            raise MissingPlaidCredential(
                'Missing SECRET. Please provide Plaid secret.'
            )

        if not self.public_key:
            raise MissingPlaidCredential(
                'Missing PUBLIC_KEY. Please provide Plaid public key.'
            )

        if not self.environment:
            raise MissingPlaidCredential(
                'Missing environment. Please provide Plaid environment.'
            )

        if self.environment.lower() not in VALID_ENVIRONMENTS:
            valid_environments_str = ','.join(VALID_ENVIRONMENTS)

            raise InvalidPlaidEnvironment(
                f'Please insert one of the following environments: {valid_environments_str}'
            )

        self.client = Client(
            client_id=self.client_id,
            secret=self.secret,
            public_key=self.public_key,
            environment=self.environment
        )

        self.access_token = None
        self.public_token = None

    def get_public_token(self):
        # how do I get the access token?
        pass
```

In the docs, they're also specifying the following:

> A `public_token` (which is returned in your Link `onSuccess()` callback)
>   should be passed to your server, which will exchange it for an
>   `access_token`. public_tokens are one-time use tokens and expire after
>   30 minutes. You can generate new public_tokens as needed via the
>   /item/public_token/create endpoint.
>
> An `access_token` is used to access product data for an Item. This
>   should be stored securely, and never in client-side code. This is used
>   to make authenticated requests to the Plaid API for the user. By
>   default, access_tokens do not expire, though you can rotate them; if
>   it winds up in an error state, the access_token will work again if the
>   Item’s error is resolved. Each access_token is unique to a specific
>   Item, and cannot be used to access other Items.

but this is just more confusing. Can anybody give me some advice regarding this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

basically **public_token** comes from the client side means

when you will implement the frontend-part/client-side for that Plaid to Link or to create items then the backside process for that creates **public_token** [here is the link for that (official-docs)](https://plaid.com/docs/#client-side-link-integration);
as per the docs on *onSuccess* of the  the public token generates;

and that public token will send to the server-side/backend-part [here](https://plaid.com/docs/#server-side-link-handler) and you can use that public token as per the requirements:
as follow:

```
from plaid import Client


client = Client(client_id='***', secret='***', public_key='***', environment='sandbox')

# the public token is received from Plaid Link
response = client.Item.public_token.exchange(public_token)
access_token = response['access_token']
```

Comment: figured that out eventually but still, is there a (any) way to do this without the *client* side? I mean, I'd just like to build a pure, custom API wrapper around their API.

Comment: I was confused on how to get a public token also.  I dug through Plaid's QuickStart examples and found that the Plaid client side library generates it somehow:  https://github.com/plaid/quickstart/blob/b1108f46acfc92abf15e78467757525bff646ffd/html/index.html#L311.  

Like you, I don't have a need for the Plaid front end and would like to get public tokens from the server side.  I've not found a way to do this yet, but am asking Plaid Support.

Comment: @jones-chris did you ever figure this out? in the same situation, trying to avoid using plaid's front end

Comment: @dan_g I contacted Plaid and they said I had to use their front end :(.  If you're looking for a programmatic way to pull bank data, you can use Python and OFX.  See this example:  https://github.com/jones-chris/personal-budget/blob/master/personal_budget/main.py.  It ran successfully on my local machine, but doesn't work in AWS - my guess is because of USAA client white listing....but I don't know for sure.  I hope that helps :)!